# Panda's data frame up sampling with interpolation on a non time series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have a set of data with inconsistent step sizes between the x values. Now the idea is to up sample the dataframe where x will have an increment step size of 0.5 and interpolate the y values.

I have the following df:

```
     x        y
    10183.2 -40.1
    10187.1 -41.0
    10191.0 -41.2
    10195.0 -41.5
    10198.9 -42.0
    10202.8 -42.4
    10206.8 -42.9
    10210.7 -43.4
    10214.6 -43.8
    10218.6 -44.2
    10222.5 -44.4
    10226.4 -44.6
    10230.4 -44.8
    10234.3 -44.9
    10238.2 -45.0
    10242.2 -45.1
    10246.1 -45.2
    10250.0 -45.2
    10253.9 -45.3
    10257.9 -45.4
    10261.8 -45.5
    10265.7 -45.5
    10269.7 -45.6
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
     x        y
    10185   Nan
    10186.5 Nan
    10187   -40.00
    10187.5 Nan
    10188   Nan
    10188.5 Nan
    10189   Nan
    10189.5 Nan
    10190   Nan
    10190.5 Nan
    10191   -41.2
    10191.5 Nan
    10192   Nan
    10192.5 Nan
    10193   Nan
    10193.5 Nan
    10194   Nan
    10194.5 Nan
    10195   Nan
    10195.5 Nan
    10196   Nan
    10196.5 Nan
    10197   Nan
```

Where the Nan will be interpolated based on the existing points in the original df.

Is there a way to create a new df where the x points are spaced by 0.5 based on the original x data?

I have been looking into reshape but this is only used for time series.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your new index, `reindex` on the combination, `interpolate`, and subset the new rows only:

```
new_index = np.arange(10185, 10270, 0.5)

(df.set_index('x')
   .reindex(sorted(list(df['x'])+list(new_index)))
   .interpolate()
   .loc[new_index]
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

[image: interpolation]

```
         x      y
0  10185.0 -40.25
1  10185.5 -40.40
2  10186.0 -40.55
3  10186.5 -40.70
4  10187.0 -40.85
...
```

Comment: Thank you. Great idea. Will try to figure this out. But when I try this provided code. It will not output the same as shown here.  I get the new index variable but the df stays in the same step size and the y values are not included thus not interpolated. I am using Spyder.